# Nexus access control

Tags: nexus

I wanna know with nexus I can control access of repositories.

For example I have Repo A, B and C and groups 1, 2 and 3.

Can I say that for Repo A and B just Group 1 have access and Repo C group 2 and 3 have access?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  You can configure privileges for the repositories and specify which groups can access it.

See [The Nexus Book - Managing Security](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-managing-security.html) for more details.